# On $n$-degree algebraic numbers with a special property

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, roots

Let $n\geq 2$ an integer, let $P(x,y)$ be a polynomial with integers coefficients and let $\beta$ be an algebraic number for which $P(x_0,y_0)=\beta$, for some $(x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and such that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)\cdot \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\neq 0$.

I would like to show the existence of a real $n$-degree algebraic number $\gamma$, for which
$$
P(r\gamma,\alpha)\neq \beta,
$$
for all rational number $r\neq 0$ and all real algebraic numbers $\alpha$ with degree $<n$.

This existence can be proved for many classes of polynomials, but I was not able to show this (or disprove) in the general case.

Someone could help me, please?

Comment: It fails with $P(x,y) = x+y$ and $\beta=0$

Comment: @reuns Yes, you are right I forgot to say that the rational number $r$ is nonzero. Thanks! Now for your polynomial and your beta, take $\gamma=2^{1/n}$.

Comment: any idea @reuns?